# ScrollToTop not working in react with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom, scrolltop

I have the following scrollToTop component following this github question: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/6665

Here is the component:

```
import React from "react";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useLocation, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const ScrollToTop: React.FC = (props: any) => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, [pathname]);

  return props.children;
};

export default withRouter(ScrollToTop);
```

here is my App Component:

```
function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  // fetches necessary configurations for elements img size etc.
  const configMbdApiState = useSelector(
    (state: RootStore) => state.postApiConfigurationReducer
  );

  const storeSearchValueHandlerState = useSelector(
    (state: RootStore) => state.searchValueFromInputHandlerR
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(
      postMDBConfigurationApi(
        `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/configuration?api_key=${configMbdApiState.apiKey}`
      )
    );
    dispatch(
      postMoviesGenresFetchResponse(
        `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/movie/list?api_key=${configMbdApiState.apiKey}`
      )
    );
    dispatch(
      postTvshowsGenresFetchResponse(
        `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/tv/list?api_key=${configMbdApiState.apiKey}`
      )
    );
  }, []);

  // if user clicks outside the instant results div, it removes the div from the UI

  const resetsUserSearchHandler = () => {
    if (storeSearchValueHandlerState.userSearchValue.length > 0) {
      dispatch(storesUserSearchValueHandler(""));
    }
  };

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="App" onClick={resetsUserSearchHandler}>
        <Switch>
          <ScrollToTop>
            <Route path="/" exact component={WelcomePage} />
            <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
            <Route
              path="/details/movie/:title"
              component={SingleMovieDetails}
            />
            <Route path="/details/tv/:title" component={TvShowDetails} />
            <Route path="/details/actor/:name" component={ActorDetails} />
            <Route path="/results" component={ResultsPage} />
          </ScrollToTop>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Things I have tried:

- Console logged the pathname to see if it changes in every render cycle and it does.
- I have tried to move scrollToTop and use it directly on the components and it doesn't work either.
- At the moment I'm using "any" for the props type in the scroll component. Could this be the problem ?
- I'm using NavLink from route-react-dom to direct to other paths, so I don't really know what the issue could be.

Comment: I don't see the problem in your code. Can you please add which route is not scrolling and what content is loaded in that route? I've created a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-meninsky-jvoqk?file=/src/App.tsx) with a minimal React-Router setup.

Comment: Hey! @AWolf, none of the work. I tried. All what I'm doing is using the Movies free api to display some carousels, etc. there are loads of components that Im using.